# undo file exclusion in custom jar task

Tags: java, gradle

I have a special task in my Gradle file for creating an executable (or fat) jar. This jar needs to contain an slf4j logging implementation so that there will be some output when the user runs the jar. Therefore, I want the logback jar and configuration file included in the executable jar. However, I don't want either of these to appear in the output of the built-in `jar` task.

I am able to specifically include the logback jar in the executable jar. However, I am unable to exclude the logback.xml file from the library jar without also excluding it in the executable jar. Using `include("logback.xml")` in the fatjar task causes the output jar to ONLY contain the XML file and nothing else!

Here is the relevant portion of my build file so far:

```
dependencies {
    runtime group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'MyClass'
    }
    baseName = baseName + "-executable"
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
    // include('logback.xml') //FAIL!
}

jar {
    // clients should configure slf4j themselves
    exclude('logback.xml')
}
```

How can I exclude `logback.xml` from the regular jar task but include it in the `fatJar` task?

Comment: Where is the file located? Could you just add another `from` statement to include the file?

Comment: it's in the root of the resources directory: `src/main/resources`

Comment: @lu.koerfer the from statement worked! So why does `include` work differently in the `from` statement?